# What is the best method to create a extract with 20M rows?

Tags: tableau-api

I am having the problem of creating an extract with 20M rows(since it is a long lasting process),
I wanted todo a Live Connection but since the problem is with Amazon Redshift or Data Base design Issue The reports takes a long time to preview on the server.

So I'm going to extract the data (20M rows) is there as fastest way to create an Extract?

I followed these steps that did not work,

`Method 1:`

1.Create  a extract with 10 rows

2.Publish the extract to server

3.Schedule the extract for full Incremental Extract

`Method 2:`

1.Create the view

2.Publish the view

3.Schedule the view for full refresh

please guide me on this?

Comment: When you say that neither method worked, what was the actual problem? Were there errors, did the extract not refresh correctly or something else?

Comment: you could use the Tableau Data Extract API to build the extract programmatically to help diagnose what's going wrong.

Comment: @Talvalin: Neither of them worked as in,The extract didn't happen at all,the schedules were successful on the server,Ex: I created a extract with 1 row,and scheduled it, but after the schedule(schedule successful) the extract still had 1 row in it,I expected nearly 20M rows.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to Alex Blakemore's answer is to create an empty extract on Tableau Desktop, publish that data source to Tableau Server, then schedule the data source for a refresh the following day.

[Publishing and Populating Empty Extracts](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/publish-populate-empty-extracts)

This method should work. If it doesn't then please contact Tableau Support for further assistance (providing that you have current maintenance).

Comment: Having the Tableau Server build the extract is helpful if the problem is that it takes too long to push the extract from the client up to the server. But it doesn't help if the connection to the original data source is failing. In that case, building the extract from a Python script could give you a shot at diagnosing the problem

Answer (score 3):

If the extract is not being successfully created, and you need to diagnose the problem, you can try to create the extract via a Python script or a Java or C program using the Tableau Data Extract API. It's pretty straight forward and could let you have more control over logging and debugging.

I generally recommend the first method, but be sure to publish the extract to the server separately as a data source, and then have your workbooks connect to it via Tableau Server -- rather than embedding the extract inside one particular workbook. That way you can update the data and the workbook(s) independently.

Also, for an extract of that size, try to hide the fields (columns) you don't need, filter out the rows you don't need, and roll up the level of aggregation to the highest your visualization needs. The smaller the extract, the better the performance.

There is a good series of three articles on Tableau data extracts on the Tableau blog. Here's the first one:
http://www.tableausoftware.com/about/blog/2014/7/understanding-tableau-data-extracts-part1

Answer (score -1):

Using server resources to publish your extract using -1 count extract method.

1. Create your connection, select extract and edit filter to top 1 rows.
2. Save the workbook.
3. Open workbook in notepad and look for the text `count extract = 1`
4. Change the `1` to `-1` and save the file.
5. Open workbook in tableau and just publish the data source on server.
6. Go to server and run extract refresh on server.
7. Once complete, connect to the extract from server published resource.
8. You are good to go.